# How to check abilities CanCan in view using Haml?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, cancan

Trying to check abilities in view like this:

```
...
%td= user.zip
  %td 
    - if can? :manage, user
      %td= puts "LOLo!"
...
```

Raise an error in line if:

syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end

File abilities.rb:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
  # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  else user.editor?
    can :edit, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will totally work in HAML.  Your `initialize` method has two `else` conditions - one needs to be an `elsif`

```
def initialize(user)
  # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.editor?  # Problem is here
    can :edit, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided. I didn'n implement method `admin?`, but I have another one `role?`. Change `user.admin?` to `user.role?`.